# timer counting by two instead of one

Tags: javascript, timer

i got this minesweeper game written in html/css/javascript, which in general runs pretty decently, and i put a timer in it, the timer always runs smoothly.

however once randomly when i was playing it started incrementing by two (which means the timer somehow was triggered twice without the timeout working). it never happened before as far as i know, and i tried but couldnt make it happen again, [here is a link](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/minesweeper.html), and heres the relevant code:

```
function timer() {
    if ( gameOn ) {
        timePast++;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timePast;
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    } 
}
```

timer is set in my `start()` function:

```
timePast = 0;
    //start the timer if it was stopped
if ( !gameOn )
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(timer, 1000);
```

and here is all the instances of my `gameOn` variable (other than the two above and in if statements):

```
    var gameOn = false; //(line 6) initialization
    gameOn = true; //(line 85) in start() - after the above code
    gameOn = false;//(line 154) in checkWin() function
    gameOn = false;//(line 239) in gameOver() function (triggers when game is lost)
```

here are parts (the parts that may be relevant) of above-mentioned functions:

```
function bombCheck(event) {
    var boxNum = parseInt(event.id);
    if ( bomb.indexOf(boxNum) >= 0 ) {
      gameOver();   }}

 gameOver(){gameOn = false;}
```

now for checkWin:

```
    function checkWin() {
        if ( flippedCount === ( cellAmount - bombAmount ) ) { gameOn = false; }}
```

start trigger:

```
   <input type="button" class="MtopSmall" value="start!" name = "startButton" onclick = "start();" >
 start(){gameOn = true;}
```

i know i should change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` and i will (someday), but i want to understand what is wrong here.

i have a fairly decent understanding of javascript and i am completely stumped, if anyone can tell me why this happened and/or how to fix it, that would be cool.

Comment: *"i know i should change `setTimeout` to `setInterval`..."* Not necessarily. I almost always prefer chained `setTimeout` to `setInterval`.

Comment: Your code is all chopped up and you refer to functions (like `checkWin`) that you haven't shown. This makes it very hard to help you. Please post the relevant code in a single, contiguous code block. Just omit unrelate code. Ideally, make a [self-contained, correct, complete example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't have a preference either way, but I'd like to know why you do :)

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight: No, you can't expect people to follow random links in order to help you, and off-site resources rot, making questions useless for others in the future. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @naomik: `setInterval` used to be inconsistent across browsers (whether the interval was measured from the beginning or end of each call to your function, for instance). I've just had more luck with `setTimeout`, and so I'm used to that, so that's what I keep doing... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks your reply; that's certainly useful information.